# Do I gain any XP from an AI surrendering?

Tags: starcraft-2

If you play against the AI, at a certain point it will offer a surrender, say GG, and you can either accept or decline. When this happens, there is still a number of buildings (and possibly units) left to defeat. Destroying them gives XP, which will help me level, but if I accept the defeat, then I won't be able to destroy these units. **Does accepting a surrender give me any XP? If so, is it more, less, or equal to defeating the rest of the remaining units/buildings?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Accept Surrenders ASAP!

When the enemy AI surrenders (the moment you accept it), **you get XP for every unit the AI has that would reward XP.**

The problem is, these popups are usually hidden by the victory screen itself.

[image]

So as soon as you receive the surrender offer, you should accept it, as it gives you **exactly** the amount of XP you would get from destroying all the remaining units / buildings.

Comment: (As a UT2004 announcer) Eagle eye!!!